# New wireless adapter on PC cannot see laptop on the wifi network

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-connection, file-sharing

I've just installed a TP-link Archer T9UH wireless adapter on my PC. There are two problems which did not exist with the old WiFi adapter (Edimax):

1. Internet access fails occasionally - especially after coming out of hibernation or if I've not used it for a while but left it on even though it is still connected to the router.
2. I cannot see my laptop on the wireless network even though my laptop can see the PC (and access files which are on the PC)

I don't know if they are related.

Mike.

1. IPv4 address is 192.168.1.4 - Subnet mask is 255.255.255.0 on both machines.
2. I have disallowed the PC to control the power and set the adapter as private
3. I've updated the driver

Rebooted and the PC still can't see the laptop.

Could this be relevant:

When the old adapter failed I tried to uninstall its driver but I couldn't because it said that it was incompatible with Win 10. So, I just deleted all of its software and rebooted. My new wireless network connection is called "WiFi 2" I tried to rename it to "WiFi" but couldn't because it said that a connection with that name already exists. However, "WiFi" doesn't appear on the "Network connections" window - there is only "Wifi 2" and the Ethernet connection called "Local Area Connection."

Has anyone any more suggestions please?

Aman207:

Thank you for your questions.

1. Yes, this is a USB device and, thanks, I have now disabled power control on all of the USB ports.
2. Sorry, my description wasn't clear. What I mean is that on the laptop I can map and access the PC's shared drives. But, on the PC if I try to map a network drive from file explorer and from there browse the network, I see an entry with the laptop's name but when I try to expand it a dialog pops up to say "Window cannot access \\DESKTOP-KBTL70L" (yes that **really** is the laptop's name (Windows chose it)). It then suggests that I click the "Diagnose" button. When I do this it says, after 50 seconds of checking things, "Your Broadband modem is experiencing connectivity issues" and it suggests that I restart the modem. I've done this several times to no avail. There is a "Next" button: when I click that it says "The connection between your access point, router, or cable modem and the Internet is broken". This is clearly nonsense as I can access the internet.

Thanks again for your interest.

Mike.

Comment: What subnet is assigned to the wireless adapter?  What subnet is assigned to the laptop?  Please **edit** your question instead of submitting a temporary comment

Comment: Make sure the Power Management settings for the card are disabled (do not allow the computer to turn off the card). Also make sure you set the card up as Private, not Public.

Comment: Did you install the newest drivers from the web site or the old ones included on the cd/DVD from the manufacturer.

Comment: This is a USB wireless device right? Did you disable power management on the USB controllers in device manager too? Obviously, also try different USB ports. I doubt that the name of the network has anything to do with your problem.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by this? `I cannot see my laptop on the wireless network even though my laptop can see the PC`. Are you talking about the "Network" entry in Windows Explorer? This feature is called "Network discovery" and is probably caused by a Windows firewall blockage.